# Redirect a specific URL to another in NGINX

Tags: nginx

I need to redirect a specific url containing a parameter and an anchor to a new URL:

```
/pages/page.php3?page=fond_razeni_gk.htm#GKI
```

to

```
http://www.newserver.com/o-knihovne
```

I try:

```
rewrite ^/pages/page.php3\?page=fond_razeni_gk.htm$ http://www.newserver.com/o-knihovne? redirect;
```

but this does not work. Could you please advise me what is wrong?

Answer (score 8):

try this configuration:

```
location  / {
    rewrite ^/pages/page.php3(.*)$ http://www.newserver.com/o-knihovne$1 permanent;
}
```

Comment: To get a permanent redirect instead of a temporary one, change `redirect` to `permanent`.